# How to verify a fluent interface mock chain with specific args

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Before this gets marked as duplicate, I've gone through all topics on SO that I could find and I did not see anything close to what I am trying to achieve.

I'm working on writing Unit tests for several so called 'fluent' interfaces and I am facing difficulties verifying the chain of method calls without making it too complex and unreadable. Perhaps, I thought I was missing out on something and I am just trying to reinvent the wheel. How would I go about that?

Having a mocked object `MyQuery mockedQuery`, I'd like to achieve the following:

```java
MyQuery nameQueryMock = Mockito.mock(MyQuery.class);
Mockito.doReturn(nameQueryMock).when(mockedQuery)
    .name("SPECIFIC NAME");
MyQuery addressQueryMock = Mockito.mock(MyQuery.class);
Mockito.doReturn(addressQueryMock).when(nameQueryMock)
    .address("SPECIFIC ADDRESS");
Mockito.doReturn(JOHN_QUERY_RESULT).when(addressQueryMock)
    .singleResult();
```

What I was hoping to do is more like:

```java
Mockito.when(mockedQuery.name("SPECIFIC NAME").address("SPECIFIC ADDRESS").singleResult()).thenReturn(JOHN_QUERY_RESULT);
```

But I found out that is not how it works. I tried playing around with the Answers provided by Mockito (`RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` was one of the things I tried) but I found out it worked only on the last method call of the chain as pointed out in the docs. In my case, I need to return `JOHN_QUERY_RESULT` only when both the `name()` method is passed "SPECIFIC NAME" and `address()` is passed "SPECIFIC ADDRESS".

I expect to be able to achieve this in a more neat way, as my chains include a lot more methods and taking the first approach overloads my tests with a lot of code which I hope to avoid.
**What am I missing here?**

**Update:**

Some background:
There's a `MyService` which provides a `createQuery()` method that returns a new instance of `MyQuery`. This service (`MyService`) is used in a **class** I am **trying to test**, this class does some job, but it makes use of (those) queries to retrieve information about something that it has to do. Therefore mocking `MyService` and `Inject`ing it in the tested class, also using a mocked `MyQuery` will allow me to test the behavior itself eliminating the internal implementation of `MyQuery`, just by being able to specify what the return should be on SPECIFIC query searches.

Comment: Can you add one of the scenarios you are trying to cover by doing this? I am not exactly sure what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: @second I updated the post with some background

Comment: I'd rather see some code, for example how `MyService`interacts with `MyQuery` and that `test class` . I suspect that you are trying to mock to much or the wrong thing for what you actually want to test.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your background info I came up with the following example:
(so that might be totally off base from your real case)

Lets say your TestClass has a method like this

```
public String someMethod(String name, String address) {
    return service.createQuery().name(name).address(address).singleResult();
}
```

and the test for it would look like that:

```
@InjectMocks
TestClass testClass;

@Mock
MyService service;

@Test
public void test() {

    MyQuery query = Mockito.mock(service);
    when(service.createQuery()).thenReturn(query);

    Mockito.when(mockedQuery.name("SPECIFIC NAME")
                            .address("SPECIFIC ADDRESS")
                            .singleResult())
           .thenReturn("JOHN_QUERY_RESULT");

    Assert.assertEquals("JOHN_QUERY_RESULT", testClass.someMethod("SPECIFIC NAME", "SPECIFIC ADDRESS"));
}
```

---

> In my case, I need to return JOHN_QUERY_RESULT only when both the name() method is passed "SPECIFIC NAME" and address() is passed "SPECIFIC ADDRESS".

That part would already be covered by the test, simply by the fact that if the mocks would not match you would get an `NullPointerException` instead.

Also it sounds like something that isn't relevant for a UnitTest of the `TestClass`, but instead should be relevant for a UnitTest of `MyQuery`.

---

However lets have a look at the test. We can see that every line of the test includes a operation based on a `mock`.

*What have we achieved with that test? Did we test the `TestClass`?*

No. We could have just mocked the whole `TestClass` instead and return the result directly. And mocking the `TestClass` is bad.

So my answer to that is: Nothing.

We have verifed that mockito does what is supposed to do, and chaining method calls work, but that is beyond the point of a good test.

---

*What can we do to improve this?*

I'd say a test like that is not really cut out for a UnitTest, even less for mocking, instead we should focus on an integration test.

In case `MyQuery#singleResult` has some 3rd party interactions, for example with a database, then this is something that could be mocked.

However in the end we would still need another Integration-Test for the database interaction. In that case we might be better of by restricting ourselves to only test some `Exceptions` that are normally to hard to reproduce.